# I see number in review but when I open I see nothing

Tags: support, review

I see in review column like

late answer[2]

First Post [1]

but when I click to see them to give review it shows nothing ( no post) . And when I Click back to review it shows me the same number again .
I am not getting the reason behind this , sorry for bad explanation .

Comment: Caching - it's always caching!

Comment: I take it you're talking about Stack Overflow in particular? I think that's the only site with the caching Juergen mentioned.

Comment: @PeterJ here on MSE too. (the numbers are wrong 99% of the time)

Comment: I am not getting about caching , how is it responsible ?

Comment: @varsha, because the database query is expensive (takes a while) it might only be run once a minute for example. Say we both load the page within a minute we both see the same number, but say I beat you to a first post review by a few seconds when you click on it there won't be anything for you to review.

Comment: okay , @PeterJ thanks for explaining . I got it .